# Flutter Nested array?

Tags: json, flutter

I have these JSON data

```
[
  {
    "student_id": 1,
    "studentid": 1204,
    "password": "demo",
    "name": "Amber",
    "level": "student",
    "course_name": [
      "Math",
      "History"
    ]
  }
]
```

Kindly show me the code to to achieve this :

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You don't need a nested for loop, a regular for loop will be enough.

Comment: Hi Ambitions can you show me some code?

Comment: [This](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) may help you with the JSON part.

Comment: Thanks bro fixed

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a JSON array (only one index), should be something like:

`myArray[0].course_name.forEach(course => console.log(course));`

Comment: Hi Rodolfo, I am new to programming kindly show me the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this now

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<String> getData({isShowLoading: true}) async {
    // refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
    //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    if (isShowLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://ikns.info/api/nested-array.php"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (isShowLoading) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      });
    }

    return "Success!";
  }

  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() async {
    await getData(isShowLoading: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Parsing List of Strings"),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: Text('Loading...'),
            )
          : RefreshIndicator(
              key: refreshKey,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  List<dynamic> items = data[index]["course_name"];
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                            todo: Todo.fromJson(data[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: new Card(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: new Text(data[index]["name"]),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: List.generate(items.length, (index) {
                              return Text(
                                "${items[index]}",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              );
                            }),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              onRefresh: _onRefresh,
            ),
    );
  }
}

class Todo {
  final String name;

  Todo(this.name);

  Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : name = json['name'];
}

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Todo todo;

  DetailsPage({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(todo.name),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(todo.name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** 
OnClick Math, pass Math to the other screen (same for history)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future<String> getData({isShowLoading: true}) async {
    // refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
    //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    if (isShowLoading) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://ikns.info/api/nested-array.php"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (isShowLoading) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      });
    }

    return "Success!";
  }

  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  Future<Null> _onRefresh() async {
    await getData(isShowLoading: false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Parsing List of Strings"),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: Text('Loading...'),
            )
          : RefreshIndicator(
              key: refreshKey,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  List<dynamic> items = data[index]["course_name"];
                  return new Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: new Text(data[index]["name"]),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: List.generate(items.length, (index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => DetailsPage(
                                      todo: Todo(items[index].toString()),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "${items[index]}",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              onRefresh: _onRefresh,
            ),
    );
  }
}

class Todo {
  final String name;

  Todo(this.name);

  Todo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : name = json['name'];
}

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Todo todo;

  DetailsPage({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(todo.name),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(todo.name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210042/discussion-on-answer-by-josteve-adekanbi-flutter-nested-array).

Answer (score 0):

data[index].courseName[0]

https://app.quicktype.io/ for right "model"

model.dart

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Welcome> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Welcome>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Welcome> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Welcome {
    int studentId;
    int studentid;
    String password;
    String name;
    String level;
    List<String> courseName;

    Welcome({
        this.studentId,
        this.studentid,
        this.password,
        this.name,
        this.level,
        this.courseName,
    });

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        studentId: json["student_id"] == null ? null : json["student_id"],
        studentid: json["studentid"] == null ? null : json["studentid"],
        password: json["password"] == null ? null : json["password"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        level: json["level"] == null ? null : json["level"],
        courseName: json["course_name"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["course_name"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "student_id": studentId == null ? null : studentId,
        "studentid": studentid == null ? null : studentid,
        "password": password == null ? null : password,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "level": level == null ? null : level,
        "course_name": courseName == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(courseName.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

main.dart

```
    var jsonString = [
  {
    "student_id": 1,
    "studentid": 1204,
    "password": "demo",
    "name": "Amber",
    "level": "student",
    "course_name": ["Math", "History"]
  }
];
List<Welcome> hui = welcomeFromJson(json.encode(jsonString));

print(hui[0].courseName[0]);
```

Comment: Kindly pull the repo brother https://github.com/erwinagpasa/flutter_nested_array

Answer (score 0):

*You can do this by using the for loop*

```
Column(
    children: [
      for (var course in data[index]["course_name"])
        Text(
          course,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 14.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
          ),
        ),
    ],
  );
```